# Android - Get preference from activity to broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-preferences

I'm developing an Android app but I have a problem. When I try to get a saved preference from my Activity and use it in a `BroadcastReceiver`, it tells me that string I'm looking for doesn't exist.

This is how I save the preference in the Activity:

```
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value) {                         
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
  editor.putString(key, value);
  editor.commit();
}
```

And this is how I try to get the preference in `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
String pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
  .getString("MEM1", "Does not exist");
```

Where `MEM1` is the string I saved before.

My problem is that when I read `pref`, I'm getting the default value of `Does not exist`, instead of my preference value (`MEM1`). Can someone point me to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Could you paste a code snippet where you call `SavePreference()` method?

Comment: SavePreferences("MEM1", ETIdUtente.getText().toString());
 is now i call the function !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should Use..

```
private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences("my_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
       }
```

And Then

```
String pref = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("MEM1", "Does not exist");
```

Also Make Sure Your Key Is Correct.

Comment: SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences("my_prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
Accept only 1 Int ... :(

It give me The method getPreferences(int) in the type Activity is not applicable for the arguments (String, int) error >:

Comment: Check out my edit..See how i changed the line where you pull the information out in the reciever

Comment: You should use context.getSharedPreferences(String Key, int); in your receiver.

Comment: It work :D ty!!!! ^.^ 
Btw it's 
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("my_prefs",MODE_PRIVATE); 

ty a lot :)

Comment: Ill update my answer accordingly. No Problem =). Glad to have Helped.

Comment: I find it best to use a seperate file  when using shared preferences vs. using the default ones. such as we did with my_prefs

Answer (score 1):

```
Activity.getPreferences(mode);
```

returns an instance of SharedPreferences that is specific to that Activity (as in, the XML file backing it will be named the same as the activity), while default shared preferences is specific to the application (the XML name will be based on your package name).

Either provide a custom file name every time you retrieve SharedPreferences, or stick to the default.